# Is Social Engineering out of scope unless explicitly requested?

Tags: penetration-test, social-engineering

I've seen some sample "What would you like to be pentested?" page (I can't find or remember the exact source) where *Cyber, Physical and Social* were asked separately (among other areas like Wifi, Network, WebApp, etc). Let's assume the customer does *not* request for a Social Engineering test. Whether the test is on-site or remote, there are some social engineering kind of attacks I'm not too sure about:

- Phishing (maybe with email forgery)
- Asking for secret information like passwords
- Badge cloning (I'm not sure how this is categorized)
- Making online support (human) give me unintended access to some part of the system

Those are just a few I thought of on the spot, but there are many more in some gray area, like *phishing* being between digital and social. Testers can also just get creative and make up attacks involving social engineering. Given that *Social Engineering* is not explicitly in the scope, are such "social-engineering-ish" attacks above considered *out of scope* and are not allowed?

Comment: You can probably guess what my comment is before I make it: it depends on the scope. All these questions of yours are making guesses about what a pentest might be like before you actually engage in one, or even see one. Instead of making guesses about a process and asking questions, first actually see one or be involved in one, then ask questions.